# How to get the number of each punctuation mark from a file

Tags: sed, grep, wc, tr

```
grep '[".?!"]'
```

Returns the lines that have one of these but I have no clue how to tell how many are in each line, let alone how many ., ?, and ! there are.

Comment: if gnu grep:   grep -o '[[:punct:]]' filename | wc -l

Comment: @Theophrastus Nice!  Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Are you looking for the total number in the whole file, or are you looking for the number per line?

Answer (score 1):

This will print a list of all punctuation characters found in the file, one punctuation character per line, each proceeded by the count of that characters in the file:

```
grep -o '[[:punct:]]' file | sort | uniq -c
```

I like to test by running /var/log/syslog, mine has over 150,000 lines right now.

Comment: I have a feeling the OP's asking for the number of _each_ punctuation mark. BTW, POSIX `tr` [supports :punct:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html)

Comment: @1_CR Thanks for your interpretation/correction!  That makes a much more exciting question and answer!

Answer (score 1):

To find the total number of such punctuation marks in a file, you can use `tr` to strip all others out, then `wc` to count:

```
tr -dc '.?!' | wc -c
```

Comment: Digital Trauma -- Nice user name, I can relate. :-)  See @1_CR's comment on my answer (which was almost exactly like yours before my last edit).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an awk script that looks for lines containing `.`, `?`, or `!`. It prints the line number of each line that contains any of those punctuation marks, the number found of each mark, plus the total number of marks on that line. At the end of the data it prints grand totals.

You can pass it multiple filenames on the command line and it will behave as if you've `cat`ted all the files together, but it's fairly easy to modify this script to process each file individually.

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Count punctuation marks
# See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/239894/88378
# Written by PM 2Ring 2015.10.131

BEGIN{
    FS = ""
    punc = ".?!"
    fmt = "%5s: .=%s, ?=%s, !=%s, all=%s\n"
}

/[.?!]+/{
    #print NR, $0, NF
    count[1] = count[2] = count[3] = 0
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    {
        n = index(punc, $i)
        if(n)
            count[n] += 1
    }
    all = count[1] + count[2] + count[3]
    printf fmt, NR, count[1], count[2], count[3], all
    for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
        total[i] += count[i]
}

END{
    all = total[1] + total[2] + total[3]
    printf fmt, "Total", total[1], total[2], total[3], all
}
```

Here's some random data I used to test this script:

```
Some test data
.a.?? .u o..ru. !!?aarl.?...t  s
e.?a.eli?.?s.. ?.r. s.t .e.a.le!
ti h  ..rs.  ?er.t. dn!t?.?.l.?t
?.n!rer e. d..!???? a .!..a.tit.
No punctuation
!.a.n..!isda!.o a!le.d..a.!sh.t?
?!?. ..!i  hi...h iii.?..a i hh?
.h r.u?....t..s !.. a  .li?hs !.
ia tso???.tr?t .hl..i.aids l.?.?
Bye-bye.
```

And here's the output that was generated:

```
    2: .=10, ?=4, !=2, all=16
    3: .=11, ?=4, !=1, all=16
    4: .=8, ?=4, !=1, all=13
    5: .=9, ?=5, !=3, all=17
    7: .=10, ?=1, !=5, all=16
    8: .=9, ?=4, !=2, all=15
    9: .=12, ?=2, !=2, all=16
   10: .=7, ?=6, !=0, all=13
   11: .=1, ?=0, !=0, all=1
Total: .=77, ?=30, !=16, all=123
```

Tested on GNU Awk 3.1.7

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed -e'1{x;s/^/0ddsQsEsD[q]sq/p;x;}' \
    -e'/[^?!.]*\([?!.]\)[^?!.]*/!d;=' \
    -e's// l\11+s\1 /g;s/.*/pc0dds?s!s.&Q?E!D./' \
    -e's/\([QED]\)\(.\)/[l\21>q9P[\2=]Pl\2pl\1+9P[Total: ]Pps\1]x/g' |dc
```

For any line that contains any of `[?!.]` that command will first print its line number, then the count of of the characters on that line, and then a running tally for each.

```sh
printf %s\\n \? \?\!. '' hey \? '' '' \! ...hey... .\!\? |
sed -e'1{x;s/^/0ddsQsEsD[q]sq/p;x;}' \
    -e'/[^?!.]*\([?!.]\)[^?!.]*/!d;=' \
    -e's// l\11+s\1 /g;s/.*/pc0dds?s!s.&Q?E!D./' \
    -e's/\([QED]\)\(.\)/[l\21>q9P[\2=]Pl\2pl\1+9P[Total: ]Pps\1]x/g' |dc
```

---

```
1
    ?=1
    Total: 1
2
    ?=1
    Total: 2
    !=1
    Total: 1
    .=1
    Total: 1
5
    ?=1
    Total: 3
8
    !=1
    Total: 2
9
    .=6
    Total: 7
10
    ?=1
    Total: 4
    !=1
    Total: 3
    .=1
    Total: 8
```